# What does "in the space for movement thus conquered" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What's the meaning of this phrase of Michel Foucault: "in the space for movement thus conquered". The full sentence:

> **In the space for movement thus conquered**, and broadening and organizing that space, methods of power and knowledge assumed responsibility for the life processes and undertook to control and modify them.

Comment: Is there any specific aspect of the (admittedly, *verbose*) phrasing that troubles you? ELU is not a Lit Crit site. Here are thousands of instances of ["the space thus cleared"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the+space+thus+cleared%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), for example. It's just normal English.

Comment: What would you like it to mean? ;)

Comment: @Behzad - what's the source/context? Is he talking about space as a concrete contained field, or abstract concept?

Comment: @FumbleFingers - note 'conquered' in the original

Comment: @Leon: Wot? Like that one word should make any difference to "comprehensibility"? Obviously we end up with a less likely sequence of four words, but [here are four instances](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the+space+thus+conquered%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). No matter how much context is supplied, I don't see how this question can reasonably be "On Topic".

Comment: @FumbleFingers as it stands the meaning of the whole passage seems important - how methods can assume responsibility for anything is a mystery - out of personal curiosity I'd like to see if I can track down the presumably? original French and compare.

Comment: @Leon: [This](https://www.google.com/search?tbo=p&tbm=bks&q=isbn:0470655666#q=isbn:0470655666+%22movement+thus+conquered%22&tbm=bks) seems to be the full text, and [this](https://www.google.com/search?tbo=p&tbm=bks&q=isbn:0252067290#q=isbn:0252067290+%22movement+thus+conquered%22&tbm=bks) looks like a more detailed critique (I've just enjoyed figuring out how to make those links! :) I think he's contrasting the role of more primitive "biological" imperatives with more "uniquely human" motivations/spheres of interaction that increasingly dominate our lives in modern times. But it's Lit. Crit.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Agreed. And that's crit with knobs on. I now have the challenge of upping my ante on links in comments!

Comment: @Leon: I only hit on it by chance, and since you can't "edit" my comments to see how I did it, you might not twig the method yourself. Each result in Google Books has a hotlink to the citation, but on the next line (before the "snippet view" of the found text) will be something like **books.google.com/books?isbn=0470655666**. When I cut&paste that into my browser address bar and "Go", it puts **isbn:0470655666** into my Google Books search box. All I have to do then is add the relevant text string I'm looking for, and I get a (relatively short) link to exactly that text *in that specific book*

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks - it was more the hyperlinking of text in comment boxes. Do you compose in an answer box and then cut and paste, or type the a href codes in html?

Answer (score 1):

It is supposed to mean "conquered in such a way"  as an adverb. So I presume he wrote about methods of doing whatever it is that's being done, in the previous sentence.

Yet it could have instead meant "consequently" as an adverb (as well). But this doesn't seem to be the case.